# ESP32S3 printf, fprintf to stdout and LOG output with missing characters

Tags: console, printf, esp32, esp-idf

I am logging measurements from some sensors either to a file or stdout using fprintf(). When logging to a file everything works as expected but, when logging to stdout characters are being missed. Here is an example of an output:

```
2023-03-09 20:58:11, 2, 25.0, 300, 2512, 448                                                              2023-03-09 20:59:26, 2, 25.0, 300, 2508, 4481, 25.0, 300, 2023-03-09 20:58:11, 0, 25.0, 300, 3380, 532                                       
2023-03-09 20:59:31, 2, 25.0, 300, 2508, 448023-03-09 20:59:26, 0, 25.0, 300, 3376, 531
2023-03-09 20:59:31, 1, 25.0, 300, 2543, 449.
2023-03-09 20:59:31, 0, 25.0, 300, 3376, 531.
```

Adding only the missing newline chars it looks like this:

```
2023-03-09 20:58:11, 2, 25.0, 300, 2512, 448                                                                2023-03-09 20:59:26, 2, 25.0, 300, 2508, 448
                     1, 25.0, 300, 
2023-03-09 20:58:11, 0, 25.0, 300, 3380, 532
2023-03-09 20:59:31, 2, 25.0, 300, 2508, 448
 023-03-09 20:59:26, 0, 25.0, 300, 3376, 531
2023-03-09 20:59:31, 1, 25.0, 300, 2543, 449
2023-03-09 20:59:31, 0, 25.0, 300, 3376, 531
```

The program uses a command line interface based on the esp-idf console component.

- Processor: ESP32S3
- Esp-idf: V4.4
- Host: MAC OS BigSur
- IDE: VSCode
- Channel for console output: USB Serial/JTAG Controller

So far I've tried:

- Output to ESP-IDF Monitor
- Output to screen serial terminal
- Other terminal programs for mac like serial.app, etc.
- Modifying task priorities including the console task
- Changing the baud rate
- Placing the UART ISR function into RAM
- printf and variants instead of fprintf

Besides the REPL and sensor task no other process is using the serial port in any way. Has anyone had similar problems with log or print output? I have been searching everywhere but is does not seem to be a common problem.

As per @romkey's suggestion I wrote a minimal example to reproduce

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "esp_system.h"
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"

static char *rndstr(char *str, size_t size)
{
    const char charset[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQURSTUVWXYZ         ";
    if (size) {
        --size;
        for (size_t n = 0; n < size; n++) {
            int key = rand() % (int) (sizeof charset - 1);
            str[n] = charset[key];
        }
        str[size] = '\0';
    }
    return str;
}

static void print_task(void *arg)
{
    static char some_str[50]; 

    srand(time(NULL));

    while(1)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            rndstr(some_str, sizeof(some_str));
            fprintf(stdout, "*%s*\n", some_str);
        }
        vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(1000));
    }
}

static void print_task_start(void)
{
    TaskHandle_t print_task_handle;

    // APP_CPU_NUM: doesn´t work
    // PRO_CPU_NUM: works
    // tskNO_AFFINITY: works except for the first print
    // xTaskCreate(): works
    xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(
        print_task, 
        "print_task", 
        4096, 
        NULL,
        5, 
        &print_task_handle,
        APP_CPU_NUM
    );
    configASSERT(print_task_handle);
}


void app_main(void)
{
    print_task_start();
    while(1)
    {
        vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(1000));
    }
}
```

It doesn't seem to be related to the command line interface but to the CPU core the printing taks runs on.

When using xTaskCreatePinnedToCore() on

- APP_CPU_NUM: doesn´t work
- PRO_CPU_NUM: works
- tskNO_AFFINITY: works except for the first print

When using xTaskCreate() it works

Comment: Hi @CHRISTOF CLAUDIO REINARZ BLASS, welcome to Stack Overflow. Does this problem still happen if you make a copy of your program and remove everything other than the serial output? It's difficult to help you without actually seeing your code; please edit the question to include a [minimal, reproducible example of code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the problem.